# Role-Base Access Control in Azure web and database

Tags: azure, web-applications, rbac, azure-sql-database

I want to assign some users of my Azure project Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) so that they can

1. contribute to the website/webapp (like a website contributor) AND
2. Can manage SQL databases, but not their security-related policies (like a SQL DB Contributor)

Does anyone know if there is a specific role which meets this demand or do I have to define a "Custom Roles in Azure RBAC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need permissions not included in either [SQL DB Contributor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/#sql-db-contributor) and [Website Contributor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/#website-contributor), those would seem to be sufficient. You should be able to assign both to the same user and have the functionality you described.

It also depends on your definition of "contribute to the website/webapp"; if you're talking management on the portal side, that role should be sufficient.

If you need to add other permissions on an ad-hoc basis, you can [define your own role](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-custom-roles/).