# What is the difference between roles and scopes in Azure's role-based access control (RBAC)?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-control

I'm reading the [What is Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC)?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) article in the official docs, but it is hard to discern how scopes and roles are different.

Read the following threads, but didn't find them helpful, because:

- [`stackoverflow`: Scope/Role/Group Based Access Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416152/scope-role-group-based-access-control)

  It seems that the question isn't really what I'm asking, and the answers don't seem to agree with what I read. (Then again, this may be just poor reading comprehension on my part.) Anyway, the thread is from 2015, and the last update was in January 2016.
- [`stackoverflow`: Is Microsoft Azure's Access Control service authentication model the same as role based access control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053138/is-microsoft-azures-access-control-service-authentication-model-the-same-as-rol)

  Doesn't expand on RBAC, only on AAC.
- [`stackoverflow`: Role-Base Access Control in Azure web and database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147028/role-base-access-control-in-azure-web-and-database)

  Only links to official docs or not related to this question.
- [`stackoverflow`: What is the correct use of scopes and app roles in an Azure AD web api with user and daemon clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775739/what-is-the-correct-use-of-scopes-and-app-roles-in-an-azure-ad-web-api-with-user)

  Doesn't even try to explain roles vs. scopes.

Answer (score 7):

[Azure's RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) is an authorization scheme

- (WHO)    to allow "*an entity*" (or "*identity*")  (in official terms, **security principal**)
- (HOW)    to access     (i.e., perform actions) (in official terms, **role**)
- (WHAT)  on a "*set of resources*"                    (in official terms, **scope**).

---

### 1. Building blocks of RBAC

#### 1.1 Security principal<sup>**1**</sup> (the WHO)

The "*entity requesting access to Azure resources*" is formally called a **security principal**, and it can be one of the following: `user`, `group`, `service principal`, `managed identity` (MSI). (All these are commonly referred to as ***identities*** throughout the docs.)

This image from the docs

[image]

but a more accurate depiction would be:

```
security
principal
    │
    ├─► user
    │
    ├─► group
    │                  managed
    └─► service  ────► identity
        principal      (MSI)
```

The definitions (taken from [Steps to assign an Azure role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps) article in the official docs):

- **`user`**

  > An individual who has a profile in Azure Active Directory. You can also assign roles to users in other tenants. For information about users in other organizations, see [Azure Active Directory B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/what-is-b2b).
- **`group`**

  > A set of users created in Azure Active Directory. When you assign a role to a group, all users within that group have that role.
- **`service principal`**

  > A security identity used by applications or services to access specific Azure resources. You can think of it as a user identity (username and password or certificate) for an application.

  or

  > "*An application whose tokens can be used to authenticate and grant access to specific Azure resources from a user-app, service or automation tool, when an organization is using Azure Active Directory*"
  >
  > In essence, by using a Service Principal, you avoid creating “fake users” (we would call them service account in on-premises Active Directory…) in Azure AD to manage authentication when you need to access Azure Resources.
  > <sup>(from [Demystifying Service Principals – Managed Identities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/demystifying-service-principals-managed-identities/#service-principal))</sup>

  See also: [Create an Azure service principal with the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest#what-is-an-azure-service-principal)
- **`managed identity`**

  A managed identity (MSI) is [a special kind of service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types) that is assigned to [an Azure resource that supports wielding managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status) to access other Azure services / resources without credentials. (See [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893103/what-is-a-managed-identity-msi) for more.)

Additional reading:

- ![`devblogs.microsoft.com` Demystifying Service Principals – Managed Identities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/demystifying-service-principals-managed-identities/)
- [`endjin.com`: Managing applications using Azure AD, service principals and managed identities: A permissions story](https://endjin.com/blog/2019/01/managing-applications-using-azure-ad-service-principals-and-managed-identities#:%7E:text=The%20security%20principals%20are%20given,it%20is%20a%20user%20principal)
- [`stackoverflow`: Difference between Service Principal and Managed Identities in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322079/difference-between-service-principal-and-managed-identities-in-azure)

#### 1.2 Scope (the WHAT)

The official definition is that "*a scope is the **set of resources** that the access applies to*".

I like this simplified view, because, in the end, a **scope** does resolve to a **set of resource**, but more precisely it refers to an entity in a hierarchical tree structure, each of which has authority over an Azure resource:

- scope =/= Azure entity
- scope === **resources assigned to** Azure entity

[image]

The [Understand scope for Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/scope-overview) is one of the most straightforward article in the Azure docs with great examples.

#### 1.3 Role (the HOW)<sup>**1**</sup>

As in, ***how*** is the security principal allowed to access the resource (i.e., scope).<sup>**2**</sup>

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview#role-definition) are pretty straightforward about this one:

> A ***role definition*** is a collection of permissions. It's typically just called a **role**. A role definition lists the actions that can be performed, such as read, write, and delete.

### 2. Role assignments - putting it all together<sup>**1**</sup>

> A **role assignment** "*[is the process of attaching a role definition to a user, group, service principal, or managed identity at a particular scope for the purpose of granting access.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview#role-definition:%7E:text=A%20role%20assignment%20is%20the%20process%20of%20attaching%20a%20role%20definition%20to%20a%20user%2C%20group%2C%20service%20principal%2C%20or%20managed%20identity%20at%20a%20particular%20scope%20for%20the%20purpose%20of%20granting%20access.)*"

That is, it is the application of a **role definition** to a security principal with a given scope. (I call **role assignments** "RBAC access rules" because it makes all this easier to remember and relate to.)

---

#### Footnotes

[1]: The distinction between **role definitions** (a.k.a., roles) and **role assignments** wasn't clear to me because of the wording in the docs. For example, in [Azure built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles), [`Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) is described as a role that grants "*full access to manage all resources*", which in my interpretation would make it more than a **role definition** (i.e., role definition + scope), but its JSON representation makes it clear: all these are pure roles and the only mention of scopes relates to a restriction of what scopes can be assigned to them during **role assignment** (see [`AssignableScopes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-definitions#assignablescopes)).

[2]: Yeah, this one was a bit forced...